# How to install FANN for PHP on Windows 10?

Tags: php, installation, windows-10, fann

I followed these steps to install FANN on PHP but couldn't make it work :

1. Add `php_fann.dll` to `C:\xampp\php\ext`
2. Add `doublefann.dll` to `C:\xampp\php`
3. In `php.ini` I added -> `extension=php_fann.dll;`
4. In `php.ini` I set `extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext"`
5. Restart Apache.

I use:

- Windows 10
- PHP version 7.1.11 Thread safety: enabled
- Apache: 2.4.29
- Pear version: 1.10.1

But both `var_dump(function_exists("fann_create_standard"));` and `var_dump(extension_loaded('php_fann'));` return `False`. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble with wampserver, I followed [these advises](https://github.com/bukka/php-fann/issues/13) to download the good dll. Then I did the following steps to make it working:

- Added "php_fann.dll" to the "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10\ext" and
  "C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.35\bin" folders.
- Added "doublefann.dll" to the "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10" and "C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.35\bin" folders.
- Added "extension=fann" to php.ini and phpForApache.ini
- Restarted all services

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use PHP FANN on windows 10. I did the following steps:

1. Downloaded version corresponding to my environment at  http://pecl.php.net/package/fann/1.1.1/windows.
2. Added "php_fann.dll" to my "PHP\ext" folder.
3. Added "extension=php_fann.dll" to my php.ini